# I am getting error message when I run the application file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am having trouble running the server file in this solution .
removed the other solution that was in the same directory
Did npm install for passport. help please I am not sure what else to look at

```html
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" -r dotenv/config C:\Users\name\CSC3916_HW2\server.js
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'passport-http'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\name\CSC3916_HW2\auth.js
- C:\Users\name\CSC3916_HW2\server.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\name\CSC3916_HW2\auth.js:3:21)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\name\\CSC3916_HW2\\auth.js',
    'C:\\Users\\name\\CSC3916_HW2\\server.js'
  ]
}

Process finished with exit code 1
```

[Server config settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WP87b.png)

Comment: Why you've put them into a code snippet? Use ` ` or 4+ spaces to have code format.

Comment: Are you sure you have installed the necessary dependency `passport-http`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the below comment
"Are you sure you have installed the necessary dependency passport-http? –
Terry
1 min ago"

I installed npm passport-http that resolved it